# Missing DLL while installing SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition

Tags: installation, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-r2

My problem in short terms: I can't install SQL Server 2008 R2 because of a missing .dll named `cig5kjsx.dll`

My situation/environment:
I downloaded the SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard edition (german) from the MSDN shop of my university. Now I tried to install it in a VM on a x64 Windows Server 2008 R2 OS with all updates installed (at least all available on windows update).

Problem: it stops while installing the Setup Support files giving me a fail-popup it misses cig5kjsx.dll at %filepathofinstallationfiles%\1031_DEU_LP\x64\setup\sqlsupport_msi\PFiles\SqlServr\100\Setup\fe72iemr\x64\de\cig5kjsx.dll

What I tried before posting was:

- Re-Downloading and re-installing - same behaviour.
- Looking in the file system: seems like no `/de/` folder is there at the installer directory. No `cig...dll` either.
- Found Google Solution, said: "Download/Install SP1 or 2 for SQL Server 2k8 r2 first (as far as it could go without SQL Server installed), then install SQL Server itself"- result: now it stops at the actual installation, not at the installation of Setup Support Files.
- Install it with another user account with administrator privileges (first install was done with "normal" admin-account).

So, I'm definitely out of Ideas at the moment and I hope you could help!

Best Regards,
dominik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, or more precise the workaround is: the german installation pack from msdnaa is corrupted at the moment. I tried it using the english version of SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard and it worked without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

What is the current state? When you say it stops at installation - are you getting any error message? You can also try creating a slipstreamed SP2 installation of R2 using the procedure documented at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/petersad/archive/2011/07/13/how-to-slipstream-sql-server-2008-r2-and-a-sql-server-2008-r2-service-pack-1-sp1.aspx and see if that helps you resolve the problem.